# Sudden error "activation of network connection failed" for one particular wi-fi connection. 19.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet, 19.04

My wi-fi has been working fine until a couple of days ago when I booted up and now it won't connect to one network in particular, giving the error "activation of network connection failed".

What I have tried:

1. Ethernet cable. The network connected correctly in this case.
2. Connecting to other wi-fi networks. All other networks connect correctly, it is just my home wi-fi that won't.
3. Reinstalling network-manager. No change.
4. Reboot and leave laptop unplugged for a day. Same issue on restart.

Could someone please point me to how I can start solving the problem? Is it possible to look at the network connection logs for example? (Sorry, am linux noob)

OK, log from journalctl below, showing the error:

```
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6176] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'BTHub6-P2KG' (d19bdb2b-db85-4002-a776-82e006da179b)
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6178] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="d19bdb2b-db85-4002-a776-82e006da179b" name="BTHub6-P2KG" pid=1590 uid=1000 result="success"
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6180] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6185] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6191] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6196] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'BTHub6-P2KG' has security, but secrets are required.
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6196] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6199] sup-iface[0x561c7cc99a10,wlp3s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6235] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6257] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6267] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'BTHub6-P2KG' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6270] Config: added 'ssid' value 'BTHub6-P2KG'
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6270] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6270] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6271] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6271] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6627] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> authenticating
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.6627] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: ready -> authenticating
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.9235] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 07 17:42:33 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925753.9236] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 07 17:42:34 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925754.0294] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 07 17:42:34 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925754.0295] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 07 17:42:35 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925755.0966] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 07 17:42:35 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925755.0966] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 07 17:42:35 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925755.3802] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 07 17:42:35 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925755.3803] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 07 17:42:35 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925755.8865] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 07 17:42:35 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925755.8866] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 07 17:42:36 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925756.9525] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 07 17:42:36 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925756.9526] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 07 17:42:37 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925757.2996] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 07 17:42:37 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925757.2996] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 07 17:42:38 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925758.3066] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 07 17:42:38 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925758.3067] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 07 17:42:39 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925759.3729] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 07 17:42:39 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925759.3730] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 07 17:42:39 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925759.6801] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 07 17:42:39 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925759.6803] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 07 17:42:44 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925764.6875] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 07 17:42:44 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925764.6876] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jun 07 17:42:49 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925769.7583] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 07 17:42:49 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925769.7584] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jun 07 17:42:50 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925770.0638] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 07 17:42:50 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925770.0639] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jun 07 17:42:58 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <warn>  [1559925778.6354] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jun 07 17:42:58 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925778.6356] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 07 17:42:58 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925778.6388] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jun 07 17:42:58 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <warn>  [1559925778.6403] device (wlp3s0): Activation: failed for connection 'BTHub6-P2KG'
Jun 07 17:42:58 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925778.6418] device (wlp3s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 07 17:43:00 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925780.0644] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jun 07 17:43:00 hedgehog-X550CL NetworkManager[875]: <info>  [1559925780.0647] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
```

So it seems like it gets in a loop of "supplicant management interface state: ready -> authenticating" and then "supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected" and eventually times out.

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show "connection logs". `man journalctl` will explain more about the command. You can also restrict the log message time window with the `--since=` and `--until=` (they want a time/date spec in `date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` format.

Comment: OK thank you very much - I have now added the paste from journalctl showing it trying and failing to connect. Please let me know if that's alright!

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I feel incredibly stupid.

I was blindsided by the fact that all my other devices connected normally, so I thought it wasn't a problem with my router.

All I had to do was turn off wifi on my laptop, restart the router,and turn wifi back on. I was so focused on the problem being on my computer that i didn't even touch the router itself! Still, it is strange that all my other devices, windows android etc, worked fine.
Thanks anyway and I hope this helps another idiot like me.